# How can i make breadcrumbs/show screens path in react native (I am using react navigation v5)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I want to show the path of the screen/breadcrumbs as I navigate into my nested stack navigator, I am using react-navigation v5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating a custom component for the headerLeft option on each screen https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headerleft

The custom component would have a horizontal list of buttons. You can hook up the buttons to react navigation using the useNavigation hook https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/

You can show and hide the buttons depending on which screen you are on. The useNavigationState hook can be used to figure out what the current screen is https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation-state/

Comment: I didn;t understood the part of showing and hiding the button by getting the current state can you please give an example.

Comment: If your stack of screens looks like the following A -> B -> C -> D and you are on screen C then you would only want to show active links for A and B, a disabled link for C and nothing for D. When you are on screen D you would want to show active links for A, B and C with disabled link for D. For this you need to know when you are on each screen. You can use the useNavigationState hook to know which screen is currently active.

Comment: ok, then I have to check on each custom component that which screen I am and only show links less then or equal to the current screen, am I right?

Comment: That right but you would only need one custom component but you can use the same component on all the screen in the stack.

Comment: Yes, I will try these steps and will let you know, if some help needed cause I am beginner :( .. Thank you soo much :)